# jQuery equal div heights with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, css, height

I am trying to achieve columns of equal height, one of which contains an expanding menu.

I *nearly* have it working using the code below (based on [this code](http://blog.huidesign.com/wp-content/demo/equal_height/equalColumnDynamic.html)). You can see the columns are equal heights on [this page](http://chantalorganics.co.nz/wordpress/top-products/) and [this page](http://chantalorganics.co.nz/wordpress/).

The only problem is that on the latter page, and any other short pages, there is a space below the content. Is the calculated height including the hidden submenu? If so, can I stop it doing this or do I need to use different code?

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

The simplified HTML:

```
<div id="body-container">
<div id="primary-menu">
  <div class="menu">
  <ul>
  <li>Menu item</li>
  <li>Menu item</li>
  <li>Menu item
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="float: none; display: none; visibility: hidden;">
    <li>Submenu item</li>
    <li>Submenu item</li>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
Main content
</div>
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
    function equalHeight(){
        var heightArray = jQuery("#body-container>div").map( function(){
                 return  jQuery(this).height();
                 }).get();
        var maxHeight = Math.max.apply( Math, heightArray);
        jQuery("#container").height(maxHeight);
        jQuery("#primary-menu").height(maxHeight);
            }
    equalHeight();
});
```

Comment: I had this similar question a while back. Look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821184/each-in-a-div-element-find-a-child-element-set-height-based-on-its-content

Comment: Thanks Dejan, but this works just the same as the code in my question. That is, it seems to include the hidden menu in its calculations and so leaves a large gap on the homepage and other shorter pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try using visiblity:collapse instead of visiblity:hidden.... Because hidden hides the content but it has the space of the content calculated... But collapse hides the content along with the space... [try this...](http://w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_visibility_collapse)

Comment: Thanks lakshimi, but `visiblity:collapse` doesn't seem to hide the space for me (Firefox and Chrome for Mac)

Comment: for mac it ll not work in chrome.. but i think it ll work for ff... [check it...](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns.html)

Comment: Ok, thanks again lakshmi, but I would really like it to work in Chrome too. Plus... shouldn't this only be used on table elements?

Comment: Ya u are right... only while using in table it acts as collapse... on other places collapse acts as hidden only... did u try this code without visiblity... like <ul class="sub-menu" style="float: none; display: none;"> .... This way....