# dynamically change height of div jquery on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code from [.each() in a div element, find a child element, set height based on its content (advanced?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821184/each-in-a-div-element-find-a-child-element-set-height-based-on-its-content)
its working fine on page load but not working with window resize please help

```
$('#col-main > div').each(function () {
    var tmpHeight = 0;
    $(this).find("h2").each(function() {
        tmpHeight = $(this).height() > tmpHeight ? $(this).height() : tmpHeight;
    });
    $(this).find("h2").height(tmpHeight);
});
```

Adding working code on page load
from this code I get height of taller div (column) ".demographcont" in a row (".box") which i set to other divs in the row for same height ".demographcont". its worked for all rows.
[image: on normal size]

Not worked on window resize
 its reset the height and the height will come as per content
[image: window resize]

after page refresh on window resize
[image]

```
/* code for adding height to div as per content */
    function setHeight() {
        $('.box').each(function () {
            var tmpHeight = 0;
            $(this).find(".demographcont").each(function () {
                tmpHeight = $(this).height() > tmpHeight ? $(this).height() : tmpHeight;
            });
            $(this).find(".demographcont").height(tmpHeight);
            // alert(tmpHeight);
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setHeight();
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        setHeight();
    });
```

Html code here

```
<div class="box clearfix">
    <div class="demographcont clearfix">
        <div class="grid_12">
            <div class="grid_5">
                <label>
                    Date of Birth:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_7">
                18/06/2013
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_12">
            <p>
                content1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="demographcont">
        <div class="grid_12">
            <p>
                content1</p>
            <p>
                content1</p>
            <p>
                content1</p>
            <p>
                content1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_12">
            <p>
                content1</p>
            <p>
                content1</p>
            <p>
                content1</p>
            <p>
                content1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.demographcont{
    border:1px solid #006599;
    padding:0;
    line-height:20px;
}

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in the context of your question? What part of it isn't working on resize?

Comment: i am adding dynamic height on div its worked fine on page load but on window resize its not working the height added by "tmpHeight" is reset as it is

Comment: I added the html code which work fine but not working on resize.  i am using fluid 960 grid layout so resize window smaller height should be resize dynamically

Comment: If you put alerts in the code and resize, does it get called? This doesn't for the resize: http://jsfiddle.net/ZaQRx/

Comment: obviously it's not going to work on resize because you already set the height inline so all h2 elements in a div have same height!

Comment: yes I get alert with old height after resize on page refresh its working fine same for alert also new height on alert message

Comment: @codedme That's what he wants. All the elements should keep the same height. So any shorter ones get set to be taller.

Comment: Please add to your question a description of what is wrong after a resize and what is right when the page is loaded but before resizing. People keep not knowing.

Comment: Oops. Found a bug in my fiddle. Try this modified one which, by the way, doesn't seem to be doing anything wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/ZaQRx/2/ And its got your code pretty much exactly.

Answer (score 1):

OK this is what I got from your question :

You want to find maximum height of  div.demographcont elements and set this value for the rest of elements .After page load we will have some thing like this

```
<div class="box clearfix">
    <div class="demographcont" style="height:304px">...</div>
    <div class="demographcont" style="height:304px">...</div>
</div>
```

Now again on window resize you want to do the same thing but as I told you in comment it's not possible because you already set the same height inline.Otherwise I'm not getting your question.

So try adding auto height property then doing the rest of proccess:

```
 function setHeight() {
    $('.box').each(function () {
        var tmpHeight = 0;
        $(this).find(".demographcont").each(function () {
        $(this).height('auto');
            tmpHeight = $(this).height() > tmpHeight ? $(this).height() : tmpHeight;
        });
        $(this).find(".demographcont").height(tmpHeight);
        // alert(tmpHeight);
    });
}
```